# Change the Font of some words in selected sentences

Tags: vba, ms-word

`Forward := True` would only change the color of the words in myArray from the cursor location to the end of the file.
I'd like to apply to only sentences selected. I didn't find a command. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
Dim rng As Word.range
Dim i As Long
Dim myArray

myArray = Array("FROM", "ADD", "MAYBE"......)
For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)
Set rng = Selection.range
With rng.Find
    .Text = myArray(i)
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

Do While .Execute (Forward := True) = True
    rng.Font.Color = RGB(100, 150, 255)
Loop
End With

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation you need to use different type of replacement part of the code. Therefore, instead of this part of your code:

```
With rng.Find
'... remove everything within With...End With structure
End with
```

you should use something like this one:

```
With rng.Find
    .Text = myArray(i)
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True

    With .Replacement.Font
        .Color = RGB(100, 150, 255)
    End With
    .Execute Forward:=False, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Code is **tried and tested** and it's working fine.

Comment: 3. it matches `FROM`, `"FROM"`, `&&&FROM`... I only need to match the first `FROM`, the one without any punctuations. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! 1. I don't think `Forward:=False` in the second to last line & `With .Replacement.Font
        .Color = RGB(100, 150, 255)
    End With`
    is necessary. What about `.Replacement.Font.Color = RGB(100, 150, 255)`?

2. I don't understand why you set `.Format` to `False`

Comment: for points 1 & 2- make some experiments, if anything works with other settings you could use them. I provide code which works. There are usually two (or more) ways to get what you need with VBA. Regarding point 3- there could be lot's of possible situation as I see therefore you will need to figure them out on your own with [this helpful link](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)